# ActionBar API in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new to android and I'm trying to use ActionBar.I've read the documentation where it simply states that if you use android greater that 3.0 (i think) you use it by default.I've also downloaded some sample code and built it,and while it runs as it should run (meaning that the actionBar appears).In order to run it i had to import another project so that it could compile correctly.Do you know how i can effectively use the actionBar API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock at http://actionbarsherlock.com is an Android library for implementing the action bar design pattern using the native ActionBar on 3.0+ and a third-party library on pre-3.0.

If you want example check [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar)

Comment: yeah I've also come across this api but i thought to go with the one that google released.You think  should go with actionBarSherlock?
I will sure have a look though thank you

Comment: I can also recommend ActionBarSherlock. It is very clever downport that uses the google actionbar on all devices that have it >= 4.0 and emulates the complete API for older devices.

Comment: Ok,I'm gonna go with actionBarSherlock then.Thank you both for your time.